# Simple command not executing on start up

Tags: 13.10, startup-applications

I want a simple command    `mv ~/Downloads/*.torrent ~/Torrent-Backup/`    to be run everytime the system starts up.

But though the commands works perfectly by itself, scheduling it as startup application does not work.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a command to be scheduled at startup, you should use full paths, not `~`:

```
sh -c 'mv /home/username/Downloads/*.torrent /home/username/Torrent-Backup/'
```

Replace `username` with your user name.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work.

Comment: @charlie Try again with more attention ;)

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I couldn't get it to work using either of the below : `mv /home/<uname>/Downloads/*.torrent /home/<uname>/Torrent-Backup/`    or     `/bin/mv /home/<uname>/Downloads/*.torrent /home/<uname>/Torrent-Backup/`

Comment: @charlie And is working from terminal?

Comment: Yes Sir!! From Terminal, everything works like a charm... not a juju one ;)

Comment: @charlie And how did you scheduled it as startup application? Other apps works if you put them to run at startup?

Comment: Startup Applications >> Add >> Command field

Comment: @charlie Also, you can give a try to this command: `sh -c 'mv /home/<uname>/Downloads/*.torrent /home/<uname>/Torrent-Backup/'` (so: `sh -c '<command>'`). Other apps works if you put them to run at startup?

Comment: This command with **sh** works! Thank you...  Do you have any possible explanation of why the simple command won't work unless run as a shell?

Comment: @charlie Probably because the `$SHELL` environment variable is not defined at that moment. For this you have to call an interactive shell like `sh`, or `bash` or other.

Answer (score 1):

Cron requires that the command have the absolute path `/bin/mv`.

Furthermore, since your running this command on startup, `~` won't work either, because this point to the user's home directory. Use `/home/user_name/Downloads` and `/home/user_name/Torrent-Backup/` instead. Or run after logging in.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work.